# How to make a parent element click thought and still maintaining background on top of child elements

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, when using background: linear-gradient(); on parent element, child elements can`t be clicked, trying pointer-events: makes child element not be under the parent element background.

In summary I want to be parent element (.shop-catalog-items) with background, and click thought, and child elements (.shop-catalog-item1) don't be on top of my parent element background.

HTML:

```
        <div class="upper-catalog">
            <div class="shop-catalog-items">
                <div class="shop-catalog-item1">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="image.jpg">
                        <p>Text</p>
                        <div class="shop-catalog-item1-rating">
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i> 
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-catalog-item2">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="image.jpg">
                        <p>Text</p>
                        <div class="shop-catalog-item2-rating">
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .shop-catalog-items {
      border-top: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
      display: flex;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.795), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.795));
      pointer-events: all;
    }

    .shop-catalog-item1 {
      margin: 3vh;
      padding: 1vh;
      border-radius: 2vh;
      background-color: #A29BDD;
      border: 0px solid  white;
      min-width: 400px;
      z-index: -1;
      pointer-events: all;
    }
```

shop-catalog-item1 and shop-catalog-item2 have the same style code.

Comment: Are ou allowed to change the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is where you are placing the linear-gradient.  You can't use a `z-index: -1` and have pointer events.  Also, if you set the pointer events to none on your scrolling container, you'll lose the scroll.

What you want to have is the scrolling container inside a wrapper and then use that wrapper as the positioned container for an absolutely placed element which is above all of the others with your gradient in it.  Using a separate element means you can set the pointer-events property to none on that element without affecting the links or the scrolling behavior of the other elements.

You can add the gradient element with an ::after pseudo element so that you don't have to have it in your markup:

```css
.catalog-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.catalog-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 85%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### Working snippet:

```css
/* mini reset */

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

/* Catalog CSS */

.catalog-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.catalog-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 85%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  pointer-events: none;
}

.shop-catalog-items {
  --spacing: 1rem;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: var(--spacing);
  gap: var(--spacing);
}

.shop-catalog-item {
  padding: var(--spacing);
  border-radius: 2vh;
  background-color: #A29BDD;
  color: white;
}

img {
  --size: 15rem;
  display: block;
  height: var(--size);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: var(--size);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="catalog-wrapper">
  <div class="shop-catalog-items">
    <div class="shop-catalog-item">
      <a href="#" onclick="console.log('clicked 1')">
        <img src="https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg">
        <p>Backpack</p>
        <div class="shop-catalog-item-rating">
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i> 
        </div>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="shop-catalog-item">
    <a href="#" onclick="console.log('clicked 2')">
      <img src="https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71-3HjGNDUL._AC_SY879._SX._UX._SY._UY_.jpg">
      <p>Shirt</p>
      <div class="shop-catalog-item-rating">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
    <div class="shop-catalog-item">
    <a href="#" onclick="console.log('clicked 3')">
      <img src="https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71li-ujtlUL._AC_UX679_.jpg">
      <p>Jacket</p>
      <div class="shop-catalog-item-rating">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```